# Storage requirements for mainnet/testnet cardano nodes?

Tags: cardano-node, node

Does building a Cardano node on testnet takes less storage than mainnet?

If so, what are the approximate storage requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the testnet takes less storage. This is what I got when I installed them a month ago:

> Testnet: 11 GB

> Mainnet: 46 GB

I haven't updated it again, but it's roughly around those number

Comment: Mainnet sits currently at 77 gb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the disk storage for `testnet` is vastly smaller than for `mainnet`.

On my machine the `mainnet` disk storage is 76 Gig. I would be a little surprised if `testnet` even uses 10 Gig.

Comment: Just to surprise you :) , this is on the public testnet:
`$ du -sh cardano-node/db/

14G cardano-node/db/
`

Comment: Must be more on that testnet than I thought.